# UWP: Random COMException without StackTrace - unrepeatable

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have an UWP app which runs on number of clients (it's sideloaded), looking at the logs it crashes from time to time with following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Unspecified error
```

I catch the exception to send a log in the `UnhandledException` event to which I subscribe in the `App` constructor:

```
this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
```

but besides the above message, there is no stack trace, and looking at the app logs, I don't see a pattern when it happens, can't repeat it either. It looks like it happens when `ContentDialog` is showed or hidden, or when there is a navigation between pages. But that's just a guess since it only happens on customers from time to time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of our apps had a similar issue: Random untraceable crashes when navigating from page to page. It took quite much time to figure it out but the reason turned out to be that we had used **same name declarations** for different **Pages**.

For example we had a page called MainPage from which user could navigate to DetailsPage. This failed very randomly (~1/1000). The reason was that they both had the same name declaration:

```
x:Name="MyPage"
```

Another app had the same issue. It was caused by multiple **UserControls** having the same name declarations.

Comment: I have for sure several pages with `x:Name="me"` to reference it in some bindings, will try to rename it and hope it will solve that issue :)

Comment: Quick question, the *UserControls* having the same name declarations - it was about same name declarations in one xaml, or even in different xaml files/user controls?